# Mongo Express is listening, but Database and Admin Database aren't connected

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/3c-iBn73dDE?t=4761) on running the MongoDB and Mongo Express containers and linking them to my network.

I ran this command for creating a network named 'mongo-network':

`docker network create mongo-network`

It worked and now `docker network ls` produces the following:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME            DRIVER    SCOPE
211764b8aef0   bridge          bridge    local
926cb00b12c6   host            host      local
f97555f47778   mongo-network   bridge    local
58a3bdaeb7a7   none            null      local
```

I ran this command line for running the MongoDB container

```
$ docker run-d \
-p 27017:27017 \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
--name mongodb \
--net mongo-network \
mongo
```

I ran the following command line for running the Mongo Express container

```
$ docker run -d \
-p 8081:8081 \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password \
--net mongo-network \
--name mongo-express \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb \
mongo-express
```

All of the above seemed to go mostly fine but when I ran the Mongo Express container I did not get a confirmation saying:

```
Database Connected
Admin Database connected
```

[Here's a side-by-side screenshot](https://imgur.com/LIPm3jm) showing the difference between my result and the tutorial's result.

And when I try to access the database through localhost: 8081 [I get a sign in screen that does not accept my established Username and Password](https://imgur.com/URMXQJH). It just flickers refreshes the login screen. No authentication error or any such message.

I suspect that the database and admin database aren't actually connected. What am I doing wrong, here?

Running `docker ps` produces:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                      NAMES
aa9fc426ada8   mongo-express                     "/sbin/tini -- /dock…"   52 minutes ago      Up 52 minutes      0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp     mongo-express
4bc2a798845b   mongo                             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
c8da494518f5   docker/welcome-to-docker:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours         0.0.0.0:8088->80/tcp       welcome-to-docker
```

Running `docker network inspect mongo-network` produces:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "mongo-network",
        "Id": "f97555f477786a1e3927d48c77ac63a4459174009ba3cb88bc624651c7083258",
        "Created": "2023-10-09T21:10:50.494984039Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "4bc2a798845b4f2abd366f6da53d84ecd3721e4d2919f440cf75fe53fad8553e": {
                "Name": "mongodb",
                "EndpointID": "104da31c9fa8775cb6d0d600c482d61744279065d00cf5e526d73cbd8d930024",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "aa9fc426ada8224866d15d711fd2afd3c725f0d33e563ead7e22e7467c761003": {
                "Name": "mongo-express",
                "EndpointID": "6cb5638fac0560e440160175088973de6b60f72d4680573b50598c5a7212f4af",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: _"my established Username and Password"_... you haven't set any basic auth credentials

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about this? I'm just a bit confused because no part of the tutorial I was following mentioned auth credentials but it's obviously quite important. And I am still pretty new at this but want to know more so I can get this all working properly. I set my Username to 'admin' and Password to 'password' but I'm guessing there should be more to it than that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the default basic auth credentials : **user**=admin and **password**=pass

Check in the logs a line like this:

*basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!*